# Remove a container disc partition without bootcamp and do a factory reset

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

This is similar to other questions on here but I'm a little out of my depth and would really appreciate the help. I was gifted a macbook pro that had previously been partitioned to also run windows from bootcamp, which I was told had been removed. There still appears to be remnants of this and the partition remains on the drive. Windows has been deleted and so I'm unable use bootcamp to remove the partition.
I would like to do a factory reset, remove partitions, format and reinstall.

Help much appreciated!

diskutil list

[image]

Comment: First step - wipe the entire Mac & start afresh. Right now, not even the OS belongs to you & there will come a time when you need the previous owner's Apple ID & password… See [What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201065)

Comment: Thanks this is all good but It will not remove the partition

Comment: You don't need to remove the partition, you need to completely erase the disk.